# Deploy NodeJS app to Azure from VS Code

Tags: node.js, linux, azure, deployment, visual-studio-code

Created simple nodejs app in VS Code (Linux). Also created NodeJS app in Azure. How to deploy app from VS Code to this Azure app now? AZ CLI installed. I've downloaded some `MyApp.PublishSettings` file however seems it used in VS not VS Code. What is the best way to deploy then with or without git (github)?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Local Git deployment from command line (or VS Code terminal):

```
git remote add azure https://<username>@<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/<app_name>.git
git push azure master
```

If empty application already there use `force` flag:

```
git push azure master -f
```

Useful links deploying Bot Framework To Azure On Linux:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/nodejs-deployment/deploy-website
- https://blog.botframework.com/2017/04/27/Deploying-Botframework-To-Azure-On-Linux/

> **P.S.** Could be outdated since 2017.